# How do you share Macros between Visual Studio 2008 Workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

Kind of a newbie VS question : 
I'm not certain it's called a workspace in VS, but when I log in as a different user on my PC, I notice that VS acts as it is in another 'workspace' (cf. Eclipse)

The custom codesnippets are managed seperately for example, and also the Macro's I write under one useraccount are not available under another workspace.  Hence the question, can I import macros from another user-account (workspace?)

Or even better, can I choose the same 'workspace' or environment, with different useraccounts?

UPDATE : After searching a bit, I just copied the file :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\__ACCOUNT1__\My Documents\
Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VSMacros80\MyMacros\MyMacros.vsmacros
```

to

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ __ACCOUNT2__\My Documents\
Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VSMacros80\MyMacros\MyMacros.vsmacros
```

and that works fine for me now, but of course that isn't a solution in a normal case, since I overwritten the code and it is duplicated now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an ideal solution, but what I've done is grabbed that vsmacros file and moved into somewhere else on the file system (say, c:\VsMacros).  Then in Visual Studio, through the Macro Explorer, unload the existing MyMacros Macro Project by right-clicking on it.  After unloading it, Right click "Macros" and Load Macro Project and load c:\VsMacros\MyMacros.vsmacros.  You can do this in both "workspaces" and then both will reference the same file.

You can also add this to source control for versioning over time and using on multiple machines.  Unfortunately it's binary, so at least Tortoise SVN's diff tools don't help much for looking at incremental changes.

This is still not ideal, but should help a bit.